# How do I remove (custom) stopwords from unigrams but keep them in bigrams?

Tags: r

I am working with the IMDB movie ratings dataset and struggle with the data preprocessing. There are some movie-related words that appear in many ratings but are uninformative as a unigram, i.e. "film". However, if the rating says "good film" or "bad movie", that is informative and I would like to keep that as a bigram. Unfortunately, I could not yet bring my code to do this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(textrecipes)

movie_stopwords <- tibble(word = c("movie","movies","movie's","act","acts","actor","actors",
                     "actress","actresses","actor's","actress´s",
                     "film","film's","director","directors","director's",
                     "character", "characters", "character's"))
my_corpus <- tibble(sentiment = c("positive","negative","positive"),
                    rating = c("this is a good movie","this movie sucks", "this movie has a good plot"))

# print the final unigrams, bigrams and trigrams
recipe(sentiment ~ rating, data = my_corpus) %>% 
  step_tokenize(rating) %>% 
  step_stopwords(rating, stopword_source = "marimo") %>% 
  step_ngram(rating, min_num_tokens = 1, num_tokens = 3) %>% 
  step_stopwords(rating, custom_stopword_source = movie_stopwords) %>% 
  step_untokenize(rating) %>% 
  prep() %>% bake(new_data = NULL)
```

This outputs the following tibble:

```
# OUTPUT AS IS
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  rating                                               sentiment
  <fct>                                                <fct>    
1 good movie good_movie                                positive 
2 movie sucks movie_sucks                              negative 
3 movie good plot movie_good good_plot movie_good_plot positive
```

However, I would prefer the unigram "movie" to be removed, and I honestly expected the second `step_stopwords`to do just that.

```
Does anyone have an idea how to do that efficiently (i.e. for 50k ratings)?
# OUTPUT AS I WANT IT TO BE
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  rating                                               sentiment
  <fct>                                                <fct>    
1 good good_movie                                positive 
2 sucks movie_sucks                              negative 
3 good plot movie_good good_plot movie_good_plot positive
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `custom_stop_words` should be a `character` `vector` and not a data.frame/tibble

According to `?step_stopwords`

> custom_stop_words - A character vector to indicate a custom list of words that cater to the users specific problem.

```
library(tidymodels)
library(magrittr)
library(textrecipes)
recipe(sentiment ~ rating, data = my_corpus) %>% 
  step_tokenize(rating) %>% 
  step_stopwords(rating, stopword_source = "marimo") %>% 
  step_ngram(rating, min_num_tokens = 1, num_tokens = 3) %>% 
  step_stopwords(rating, custom_stopword_source = movie_stopwords$word) %>% 
  step_untokenize(rating) %>% 
  prep() %>% 
  bake(new_data = NULL)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  rating                                         sentiment
#  <fct>                                          <fct>    
#1 good good_movie                                positive 
#2 sucks movie_sucks                              negative 
#3 good plot movie_good good_plot movie_good_plot positive
```